# Java - Classes and Objects, Set isn't working?

Tags: java

I'm creating a `QuarterResult` class and basically I'm having trouble with the `setResult` method (this isn't the entire code, but the code that's necessary for my question).

```
public class QuarterResult {
    private double[] results;

    public QuarterResults() {
        results = new double[4];
    }

    /**
     * Set the results at index i to the result passed as the parameter
     * @param index (return if OOB)
     * @param result 
     */
    public void setResult(int index, double result) {
        if (index <= 0 || index >= results.length) {
            return;
        }
        else {
            for (int i = index; i < results.length; i++) {
            results[index] = result;
        }
    }
}
```

Test code:

```
myResult.setResult(0, 25.1);
assertEquals(25.1, myResult.getMark(0), 0.01);
```

> ERROR: java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<25.1> but was:<0.0>

---

Now when I changed the code as the suggestions said. I'm now getting an exception:

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>    at xxxx.QuarterResult.setResult(QuarterResult.java:25)

Which is the

```
if (index <= 0 || index >= results.length) {
```

line.

Can someone explain why this doesn't work, it seemed to work with the similar example in the textbook but just doesn't work with my code.

Comment: Change `index<= 0` to `index < 0`

Comment: Don't edit your question if there is already an answer for a certain problem in that code.

Comment: To expand on Tom's comment: If you fixed an error that was pointed out already but still get the same error then _add_ that to your question (e.g. like "I fixed this and that but still get the same error". Besides that, if you still get the assertation error after changing `index<=0` into `index < 0` then show us what `myResult.getMark(0)` is doing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`if(index<= 0 ...` - you're passing 0 so nothing happens. I guess you mean `if( index < 0 ...` instead.

Besides that, I'd not just end the method in this case but throw an exception, e.g. `IllegalArgumentException`, otherwise you might miss wrong parameters (as you obviously did).

Also look at this code:

```
for (int i = index; i < results.length; i++) {
    results[index] = result;
}
```

Is the loop really necessary? (Hint: no)

> From your comment: "still unsure what's wrong with my answer"

I assume you mean why you get the assertation error. Due to the error in your code `results[0]` was never set and thus still has the value it was initialized with, which is 0.0 for `double` variables or elements of `double[]` arrays.

Comment: Oh yeah, that makes sense why I'm getting 0 as a result, but still unsure what's wrong with my answer.

Comment: @Tom was about to do that right when you added the comment ;)

Comment: Loop was more of a test, still getting an incorrect answer without loop. Unless my results[index] = result; is wrong?

Comment: @IceArt the loop isn't executed due to the error in the if statement. When you fix that error it will run and effectively call `results[0] = 25.1` 4 times (since you pass 0 and 25.1 as parameters and the array length is 4).

Comment: @IceArt I'm not sure what I should tell you that isn't already in the answer. Read it carefully and tell me what's not clear please.

Comment: So I fixed the If statement first and now as you said I'm getting a NullPointerException, how would I throw an exception exactly for this? (P.s deleted previous comment to make it more clear of what I'm getting confused with)

Comment: @IceArt if you get a `NullPointerException` then please show us which line you get it at. The code you posted so far doesn't provide any hint since there's nothing that could be null there.

Comment: I edited the code to show which line I'm getting the error at, it's line 25 which is "if(index<= 0 || index>= results.length) {"

Comment: @IceArt Then `results` is `null` and I wonder if your constructor actually has `double[] results= new double[4];` instead of what you've posted or if you call another constructor which doesn't initialize `results`.

Comment: @IceArt that line can't produce a NPE if what you posted is your actual and complete code (read Tom's comment as well). Any chance you don't initialize `results` or call `results = null;` somewhere? Btw, you should learn how to use a debugger which will help you to find errors faster and to understand your code better.

Comment: @Tom I have results = new double[4]; in the beginning, does that count?

Comment: @IceArt Where in the beginning? You currently have it in the non-parameterized constructor, which is ok. But the question: is there another constructor? And if "yes", how does it look like?

Comment: @Tom Nope no other constructor, however I think this question is linked to another one later on which is why this gives error. I'm going to do the rest of the HW and see if the problem remains.

Comment: @Tom Oh man how wrong I was. There was another constructor hiding in the middle, I don't know if my professor put it there on purpose or just arranged them in a weird order. But after I had fixed that constructor I see about 10 green ticks on my Junit which fixed up all my problems. I was going in to a fit of rage wondering why nothing worked. Thanks for your help guys and for suggesting the other constructor! My "3 Week" project is done within 5 hours!

Comment: @IceArt So you called the `QuarterResults` constructor with arguments and never wondered why your constructor doesn't ask for them?

Comment: @Tom The sheet that I was referring off said to (1,2,3...) functions in order and had the second constructor near the middle, I didn't think there was another constructor. But I didn't think the professor would put a function down there and that's why I didn't think it through. I even put a comment "u could have put this in the start to avoid confusion 
¯\_(ツ)_/¯" on the second constructor.